# The existence of conditional expectation with respect to a sub-$\sigma$-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, conditional-expectation

I was trying to solve the exercise 3.17 from the book of real analysis by Folland and I've found a problem. The first part of the exercise is the following:

> Let $(X, M, \mu) $ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space, $ N $ a sub-$\sigma $-algebra of M and  $\nu$ the restriction of $\mu $ to $N $. If $ f \in L^1 (\mu) $, there exist $ g \in L^1 (\nu) $ such that $\int_E f \,d\mu = \int_E g\, d\nu $ for all $ E \in N $.

Let $ X $ the set of natural numbers, $\mu $ the counting measure, $ N $ containing just $ X $ and the empty set and $ f $ the characteristic function of the singlepoint $1 $ which is a $ L^1 $ function. Then, we have

$$ 1 = \int_X g\, d\nu ,$$
for some $ g \in L^1 (\nu) $. But if $ h $ is positive and $\nu $-measurable function, we can take an increasing sequence of simple and measurable functions which converges to $ h $. By definition of $ N $, a simple measurable function is a linear combination of the characeristic of $ X $ and the empty set. So, the integral of $ h $ must be 0 or infinity. Then $ L^1 (\nu) $ is trivial, and we have an absurd.

Is there something wrong in this argument? I can't see. And since he doesn't define sub-$\sigma $-algebra before (I'm assuming that is just a $\sigma $-algebra contained in the first), perhaps we need to assume more things. If I could conclude that $ N $ is also $ \sigma$- finite, then we can apply the Lebesgue Radon Nikodym to solve the problem, but the same example above shows that we don't have this in general.

Answer (score 4):

Your counterexample is correct. You have in addition to assume that $\nu$ is also $\sigma$-finite (and apply Radon-Nidokym-Lebesgue, as you say correctly). Folland refers to the example of conditional expectation from probability theory, where $\mu$ is a (probability and hence) finite[!] measure. In this case of course, $\nu$ is also finite (and hence, $\sigma$-finite). Perhaps, when generalizing the statement, the additional assumption on $\nu$ (which is no longer automatic) was just forgotten.